# How to enable Contact Trace Records in my amazon connect instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I have integrated amazon connect in my custom web application and integrated with CRM. I am currently trying to fetch the CTR of a profile. Is there any user guide or documentation provided by AWS to enable the Contact Trace Records and fetch them into UI ? I am also facing issue while trying to fetch historic report of a profile into my UI. Do I need to do any configuration or is there any API to fetch profile history ?

I am also facing issue while trying to fetch historic report of a profile into my UI. Do I need to do any configuration or is there any API to fetch profile history ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this AWS blog post:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/contact-center/analyze-amazon-connect-contact-trace-record-with-amazon-athena-and-amazon-quicksight-part-1/

You should be able to adapt this for your use case. As stated in the blog post you could transfer the CTR records to a DynamoDB database and then access this database from your UI.

Also, have a look at Connect admin guide and the corresponding documentation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/customer-profile-access.html
- https://github.com/amazon-connect/amazon-connect-customer-profiles